# elasticsearch mongo-connector stuck in "Logging to mongo-connector.log"

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastic Search and mongo.

I'm trying to make the connector work, and following the steps at: https://blog.jixee.me/how-to-use-mongo-connector-with-elasticsearch/

When I type in: `mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t localhost:9200 - -d elastic2_doc_manager -n connectortest.syncthis`

It gets stuck in "Logging to mongo-connector.log"

nothing gets written in mongo-connector.log

I'm using mongodb3.2.10, elasticsearch 2.3.5 and ubuntu 16.04
and When I type `curl localhost:9200/connectortest/_search/?pretty=1`, I get

```
{
"error" : {
"root_cause" : [ {
"type" : "index_not_found_exception",
"reason" : "no such index",
"resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
"resource.id" : "connectortest",
"index" : "connectortest"
} ],
"type" : "index_not_found_exception",
"reason" : "no such index",
"resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
"resource.id" : "connectortest",
"index" : "connectortest"
},
"status" : 404
}
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Since I'm newbie to all this, if you need to to provide something pls type in the command.

Thanks

Comment: Is your problem solved already? Please report back!

Answer (score 1):

your mongo-connector is up and running! The error message you're getting from elasticsearch via cURL tells you that there is no index "connectortest".

Get the existing indices listed via `curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices?pretty` and report back the output please!